# Something wrong with Html5 drop and drag effect

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

There are some images in one panel,I want drag them to another panel:

```
  $('#resource img').bind('dragstart', function (evt) {
        evt.dataTransfer.setData('text', this.id);
    });
```

the other panel accept the img by this :

```
        $('#draw').bind('dragover', function (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
        }).bind('dragenter', function (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
        }).bind('drop', function (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            var id = evt.dataTransfer.getData('text'),
            $(this).append("<b>Hello"+id+"</b>");
        });
```

however this doesn't work,but when I change the last event handler:

```
.bind('drop', function (evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                  alert("!!!");
            });
```

this could work,why this happend ,how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using jQuery.  Have you told jQuery to push the dataTransfer property with events?  jQuery doesn't automatically push the dataTransfer object with events.  Maybe someday that will change, but currently this workaround has to be used.

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $.event.props.push('dataTransfer');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am sure it is too late, but you can access the original event properties, i.e.:

`evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text', this.id);`